# Pandas groupby time gaps

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe called `df_merged` which outputs like below:

| index | count_date | time_gap | device | count | average_speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 00:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 00:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 00:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 00:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 01:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 154747 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 22:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 154748 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 23:00:00 | CAT17 | 4 | 16 |
| 154749 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 23:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 154750 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 23:00:00 | CAT17 | 1 | 13 |
| 154751 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 23:00:00 | CAT17 | 3 | 17 |

Here is the info on this df:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 154752 entries, 0 to 154751
Data columns (total 5 columns):

     Column         Non-Null Count   Dtype                  
 0   count_date     154752 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   time_gap       0 non-null       category      
 2   device         154752 non-null  object        
 3   count          154752 non-null  int32         
 4   average_speed  154752 non-null  int32         
dtypes: category(1), datetime64[ns](1), int32(2), object(1)
memory usage: 3.7+ MB
```

time_gap is a category because I replaced it with a `pd.cut()` function. I don't know if it's best to change the `dtype` here to groupby.

I would like to groupby `time_gap`, knowing that the `average_speed` has to be weighted by count with this function:

```
def average_speed_mean(x):
    try: 
        return np.average(x["average_speed"], weights=x["count"])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
```

I'm trying to have basically the same dataframe grouped like this:

| index | count_date | time_gap | device | count | average_speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 00:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 01:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 38687 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 22:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 38688 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 23:00:00 | CAT17 | 8 | 16 |

I tried this:

```
df_merged = df_merged.groupby("time_gap").agg({("count", sum), ("average_speed", average_speed_mean)})
```

But it doesn't seem to work out and I have no idea how I could solve this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how `count` and `average_speed` columns are calculated? From the last few rows of input and output DataFrames you have provided, it seems that `count` is the sum of `count`s for given `count_date` and `time_gap` combination, and `average_speed` is just the mean of the `average_speed`s?

Comment: It is also unclear what has to happen to `count_date`: should that be included in the grouping?

Comment: That's correct, I would add that the mean for the average_speed should be weighted based on the function average_speed_mean here above. 
Basically it weights the average speed by count. 
As for the count date, I would like to keep it but grouping by time_gap. Meaning that instead of 96 same count_date, we would return 24 row (since we have 4 row for the same hour in the time_gap. I hope it clears things up.

Comment: time_gap is the hour, so basically 24 hours in each count_date

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but if you don't include `count_date` into the grouping (i.e. `df_merged.groupby(["count_date", "time_gap"])`) then how should it be determined for the output?

Comment: You're right, but even with that I don't have the output as I would like to.
I feel like the .agg() function is not properly done but I don't know what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following give you the result you want:

```py
groups = ["count_date", "time_gap", "device"]
result = (
    df_merged
    .assign(average_speed=df_merged["average_speed"] * df_merged["count"])
    .groupby(groups).agg({"count": "sum", "average_speed": "sum"})
    .assign(average_speed=lambda df: df["average_speed"].div(df["count"]).fillna(0))
    .reset_index()
)
```

- `groups` is the list of columns I think you want to group over - adjust it, if that's not the case.
- Multiply the `average_speed` by the `count`.
- Now group over the `groups` and sum up the `count`s and `average_speed`s per group.
- Then divide the summed up `average_speed` by the total count and fill then `NaN` with `0`.
- Finally reset the index to get the group columns back.

Result for the small sample in the question is:

```
   count_date        time_gap device  count  average_speed
0  2018-12-05 0 days 00:00:00  CAT17      0            0.0
1  2018-12-05 0 days 01:00:00  CAT17      0            0.0
2  2023-05-04 0 days 22:00:00  CAT17      0            0.0
3  2023-05-04 0 days 23:00:00  CAT17      8           16.0
```

Comment: It's actually working perfectly. Thank you so much! I've been struggling a lot with this lately. 
Besides, I discovered the .div() method here (although this one is quite simple).
For my personnal understanding, why are you using brackets for the result variable?

Comment: @Para Glad to hear! Regarding the brackets: It's just the style I personally find best to read and work with. I kind of dislike the line break \, but there's no technical reason for it, only preference.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it's working very well and I find your solution pretty neat to understand it step by step.

Here is the output I get:

| index | count_date | time_gap | device | count | average_speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 00:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 1 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 01:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 2 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 02:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 3 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 03:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 4 | 2018-12-05 | 0 days 04:00:00 | CAT17 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 38683 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 19:00:00 | CAT17 | 56 | 16.339286 |
| 38684 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 20:00:00 | CAT17 | 39 | 20.179487 |
| 38685 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 21:00:00 | CAT17 | 14 | 16.142857 |
| 38686 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 22:00:00 | CAT17 | 4 | 17.500000 |
| 38687 | 2023-05-04 | 0 days 23:00:00 | CAT17 | 8 | 16.000000 |